# Windows - Easy to use video editor

Tags: video, software-recommendation, photos

I want to make a video using **photos** and **video snips** and **add titles** freely. Is there any user-friendly software to do so? I don't have much time for complicated software right now. So I'm looking for one which I can easily understand and use.

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: Windows 7. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Windows, that Windows Movie Maker — your choice. It have everyting you need for basic editing.

I myself work in Premiere, AE and Edius, but when I need something really simple, and do not have my computer with me, then using Movie Maker.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save time and learning efforts, and you can live with limited control over the end result, you may want to have a look at:

- muvee Reveal
- Magix Fastcut
- GoPro Studio
- Sony Action Cam Movie Creator

The later two are for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Windows operating system, you have the option to  the movie maker. But if you use the Apple OSX operating system, you can use Final Cut. It's also important to say that the Adobe package, which includes After Effects and Premiere, also runs on both operating systems commented - Windows and OSX.